# When working with dataloaders, how do I append the batches that I can access using enumerate into one numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I have created a Custom data set according to this tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html and wish to use this in order to get an array with my datapoints inside. I access my dataloader using enumerate like this:

```
for i, batch in enumerate(train_set, 0):
       inputs, labels = batch
       np_arr =inputs
```

What I would like to have is all my inputs and labels in one array, even if my batchsize is smaller than the samplesize of the generated inputs. However, if I just create an empty array before the loop, and append or concatenate using np.append() or np.concatenate(),like such

```
np_arr = np.array([])
```

this does not work because the empty array has a different data shape than the samples generated by the dataloader (because they are multidimensional and not an empty array). Is there any solution that is not completely ugly and includes me making an if case for the first iteration? How can I append these arrays generated by enumerate?

Or more generally:
If I have two arrays of size (300,28,28,3) and (500,28,28,3), how do I append those two to an array of size (800,28,28,3) in a non-ugly way in python?

Comment: Why are you trying to imitate lists with arrays?  It is both 'ugly' and slow.

Comment: Just concatenate the two arrays on the `axis=0`.  What's so ugly about that?

Comment: it does not work as the dimensions differ.. :)

Comment: `np.concatenate` has specific requirements regarding the number of dimensions, and how they match.  You have to pay close attention to its docs.  Arrays with shape  `(300,28,28,3)` and `(500,28,28,3)` can concatenate on axis 0.  `np.array([])` has shape (0,) so can only concatenate with another 1d array.